# Solve autonomous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

$ y''' - y = e^{2t}  $

Actually I need only homogeneous solution of $ y''' - y = 0. $

I can clearly see that it is $ e^x, $ but how to prove it?

I tried with $ \frac{dy}{dt} = v, $ but could conclude nothing.

Comment: I think that $x$ is no solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @Yola there are more solutions $(D-1)(D^2+D+1)=0$ So more solutions exist.

Comment: you have also to solve the equation $D^2+D+1=0$

Comment: Now i see, can some of you guys put it as an answer and i will vote up and accept it. If you have link for theory backed such decomposition of polynomials, it would be good too.

Comment: I think you mean $e^t$ and not $e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the roots are $\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. From the first one $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

you have also the functions $e^{-x/2}\cos \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}$ and  $e^{-x/2}\sin\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}$

Therefore the solution to the homogeneous equation is 
$y_h=A e^x +Be^{-x/2}\cos \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}+Ce^{-x/2}\sin\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} $

Comment: I think the independent variable is $t$ and not $x$.

Comment: is this a big problem?

Comment: No, it's a small problem, very easily corrected.